# RubyMotion reload sections of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, rubymotion

How can I reload specific section of a table?

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]
```

How can I write something like this in ruby's syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is in RubyMotion syntax:

```
sections = NSIndexSet.indexSetWithIndex(indexPath.section)
self.tableView.reloadSections sections, withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade
```