# Is there a way to reload data in UITableViewController using RubyMotion?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uitableview, rubymotion

I have a `UITableViewController` but I am presenting a modal controller on top of it. When the modal controller is closed I get to see the `UITableViewController` again. At this point I want to reload the data in the `UITableViewController`

Example Scenario

1. `UITableViewController` with Red Blue Green
2. present modal controller with a text field in it. Type Yellow in the text field and click a button. On button click the modal controller is dismissed and `UITableViewController` reappears
3. Reload the `UITableViewController` to show Red Blue Green Yellow

Is this possible to do?

Comment: The function is called reloadData lol. But you may want to read up on reloadRows if the table has a lot of data.

Answer (score 2):

That should be super easy:

```
// assuming this is somewhere in your UITableViewController implementation:
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

I'm going to assume that if the link below is accurate the exact same method name exists in the RubyMotion API:

http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/api/UITableView.html#reloadData-instance_method

Additional S.O. already has a very similar post for reloading only certain sections of a table view:

[RubyMotion reload sections of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587095/rubymotion-reload-sections-of-uitableview)

Comment: I am new. trying to find out how to do that in rubymotion

Comment: That is a different question, then.

Comment: In swift: `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

The code is `[tableView reloadData];` but the problem is how do you know that the modal has dismissed. If you are doing things correctly and you are dismissing the modal from the presenting viewController it's very easy:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    [tableView reloadData];
}];
```

If you are not then it's more complicated you need to set the presenting view controller as the delegate of the modal and execute a function on dismiss that will reload the data.

Comment: I am new. trying to find out how to do that in rubymotion